# newenviroment error: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup \begin{gbox}

Tags: color, environments, minipage, tcolorbox

```
    \noindent
    \colorbox{gray!25}{
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \vskip0.5cm
    \leftskip0.5cm
    \rightskip0.5cm

    Text Here!

\\\end{minipage}}
```

Code above works fine, but I don't want to repeat it every time that I want a box. However, code below doesn't work. I supose is because the **colorbox** starts in the "begin" of **newenviroment** and ends in the "end".
So, how can I solve this?

```
\newenvironment{gbox}
{
\noindent
\colorbox{gray!25}{
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\vskip0.5cm
\leftskip0.5cm
\rightskip0.5cm
}
{
\\\end{minipage}}
}
```

Comment: Wy don't you use `tcolorbox` or `mdframed`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know about `tcolorbox`, that it seems to be easier to use than `mframed`. Now I'm using the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use `tcolorbox` or `mdframed` for such a job. However, this works. I have used `environ` package.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum,environ}
\begin{document}
\NewEnviron{gbox}{%
\noindent\fboxsep=0pt
\colorbox{gray!25}{%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
\vskip.5cm
\leftskip.5cm
\rightskip0.5cm 
\BODY
\end{minipage}}%
}
\begin{gbox}
 \lipsum[1]
\end{gbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A sample with `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!5!white]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Things can get more fancier. For details: `texdoc tcolorbox` or [texdoc.net](http://www.texdoc.net)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which avoids loading the `tcolorbox` package and instead uses the `lrbox` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newenvironment{gbox}
   {\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
      \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-1cm}
  }{\end{minipage}%%
    \end{lrbox}%%
    \noindent
    \bgroup
      \setlength{\fboxsep}{0.5cm}%%
      \colorbox{gray!25}{\usebox{\mybox}}%%
    \egroup
  }


\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{gbox}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{gbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]